# chpasswd halts provision script to ask for password

Tags: shell-script, busybox, alpine-linux, ash

I'm using BusyBox on alpine linux to provision an LXC container created with ProxMax. The script is below. The problem I am having is the following line halts the provision script and asks for a password:

```
echo "${www_username}:${www_passwd}" | chpasswd
```

But if I run that command while logged in over SSH (with the variables set) it changes the password without pausing to ask for the password.

Any ideas why this might be?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ash

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset

www_username="www"
www_passwd="secret"

apk update && apk upgrade
apk add php php-fpm composer nginx curl

adduser "${www_username}" -G nginx
echo "${www_username}:${www_passwd}" | chpasswd

curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar
chmod +x wp-cli.phar
mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp

su www <<ILOVEBASH
wp --info
ILOVEBASH
```